# How to create a "my TeX folder" with MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows 10

Tags: miktex, directory, root, miktex2.9, tds

I was finding that for several days there and on lots of other forum but nothing specific for my problem. Could anyone here advice me how to crate my TeX folder for store my styles and templates there? I use the latest MiKTeX compiler with all packages on Windows 10 up to date.

Thank you very very much in advance! :-)

Marek Otýpka

Comment: You need a "myTeXFolder" with a folder `tex/latex` in it.

Answer (score 1):

You create your local TeX directory, like any other directory, with Windows explorer, (almost) anywhere you please (not in the main Root directory, though). Then you have to register it as a TeX root directory, with `MiKTeX Settings`, both as administrator and as user. For this, select the `Roots` tab, click on the `Add` and select your local root:

[image]

Don't forget your local roots has to be organised according to the TDS (`TeX Directory Structure`). Last step: after you've installed new files: refresh the FNDB (`General` tab).